# Python3 logging: Only send ERROR to screen not INFO

Tags: python, logging

What have I missed?

I have a project with lots of files and modules. I want each module, and some classes, to have their own log file. For the most part I want just INFO and ERROR logged, but occasionally I'll want DEBUG.

However, I only want ERROR sent to the screen (iPython on Spyder via Anaconda). This is high speed code getting network updates several times each millisecond and printing all the INFO messages is not only very annoying but crashes Spyder.

In short, I want only ERROR sent to the screen. Everything else goes to a file. Below is my code for creating a separate log file for each class. It is called in the `__init__` method of each class that should log items. The `name` argument is typically `__class__.__name__`. The `fname` argument is set as well. Typically, the `lvl` and `formatter` args are left with the defaults. The files are being created and they look more or less correct.

My searches are not turning up useful items and I'm missing something when I read the Logging Cookbook.

Code:

```
import logging, traceback
import time, datetime
import collections


standard_formatter = logging.Formatter('[{}|%(levelname)s]::%(funcName)s-%(message)s\n'.format(datetime.datetime.utcnow()))
standard_formatter.converter = time.gmtime

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR,
                    filemode='w')

err_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
err_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
err_handler.setFormatter(standard_formatter)

Log = collections.namedtuple(
    'LogLvls',
    [
        'info',
        'debug',
        'error',
        'exception'
    ]
)


def setup_logger(
        name: str,
        fname: [str, None]=None,
        lvl=logging.INFO,
        formatter: logging.Formatter=standard_formatter
) -> Log:
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    if fname is None:
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    else:
        handler = logging.FileHandler(fname, mode='a')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.setLevel(lvl)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.addHandler(err_handler)

    return Log(
        debug=lambda msg: logger.debug('{}::{}'.format(name, msg)),
        info=lambda msg: logger.info('{}::{}'.format(name, msg)),
        error=lambda msg: logger.error('{}::{}'.format(name, msg)),
        exception=lambda e: logger.error('{}::{}: {}\n{}'.format(name, type(e), e, repr(traceback.format_stack()))),
    )
```

Comment: What is the exact error? If I copy your code and add `if __name__ == '__main__': setup_logger('spam'); logging.getLogger('spam').info('eggs')`, I see the info message in terminal. Maybe also add a usage example.

Comment: No error I'm just getting the INFO messages in the console and I don't want them to be there. I only want to see ERROR messages in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR,
                    filemode='w')
```

and specialized config same time. Comment it out or remove, then using

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_logger('spam', "/tmp/spaaam")
    logging.getLogger('spam').info('eggs')
    logging.getLogger('spam').error('eggs')
    logging.getLogger('spam').info('eggs')
```

You'll have only ERROR level messages on console, and both in file.